# How can I check for hardware BLE support on OS X?

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've read [here](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/07/20/apple_adds_bluetooth_4_0_support_to_new_macbook_air_mac_mini.html) that Apple computers from mid-2011 should support BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). Is there a way (perhaps using the command line) to check if the device and the operating system supports BLE?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, but if you're not trying to check this support *programmatically* (i.e in a program whose code you're writing), it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might have more luck asking somewhere like [su] or [apple.se].

Comment: It wouldnt need to be necessarily programmatically, in case it is possible check it more easily through command line. But otherwise, programmatically would do it. In any case, if it is not suitable, I can delete the question from here and ask on Ask Different

Answer (score 6):

In the Mac OS X Terminal app, you can type the following:

```bash
system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType | grep "LMP Version"
```

If this command outputs >= `'0x6'` then Bluetooth 4.0 is supported and thus, BLE is also supported.

Comment: Why would Bluetooth 4.0 imply that that BLE is supported?

Answer (score 4):

1) Install LightBlue for Mac OS through the AppStore.

2) If it complains like the screenshot attached, your hardware does not support Bluetooth LE, if it does not complain "it's all good".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the CBCentralManager api for iOS and OSX is the same or very similar (not sure if that was to be expected as Im just starting with iOS and OS X), in the sense that it is possible to run the code:

```objective-c
switch ([_manager state])
{
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
        state = @"This device does not support Bluetooth Low Energy.";
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
        state = @"This app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        state = @"Bluetooth on this device is currently powered off.";
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
        state = @"The BLE Manager is resetting; a state update is pending.";
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        state = @"Bluetooth LE is turned on and ready for communication.";
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        state = @"The state of the BLE Manager is unknown.";
        break;
    default:
        state = @"The state of the BLE Manager is unknown.";

}
```

provided in the equivalent [iOS Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585218/how-can-i-detect-if-my-apple-device-supports-bluetooth-low-energy) (the credits goes to Bob there) in OS X and get to know if the device supports ble or not.

Comment: This code looks promising, but I always get CBCentralManagerStateUnknown.  (On OS X, El Capitan.)

Answer (score 1):

Click apple icon on top left corner, then click **About This Mac** -> **System Report...** on the left side click **Hardware** -> **Bluetooth**,
you will find **Bluetooth Low Energy Supported** under **Hardware, Features, and Settings**.